# Proof that f is a monomorphism

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

let $f:A \rightarrow B$ and $g:B \rightarrow A$

given that $\;\;g \circ f = 1_A$

how can I prove that f is a monomorphism?

(I'm used to prove monomorphism in a different way, so I'm kind of lost)

Comment: Are you aware of the definition of a monomorphism in a category?

Comment: i know that, if $g,h:A \rightarrow B$ and $f:B \rightarrow C$, then f is monomorphism if $f \circ g = f \circ h$ implies that $g = h$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
f \circ \alpha = f \circ \beta \implies 
g \circ f \circ \alpha = g \circ f \circ \beta
$$